# How get I the Android Core Checkbox Image files

Tags: android, image, file, checkbox

I want to use the standard checkboxes of Android, but I want to change the border color a little. Is there any option to get the original drawables as .png files?

I would like to get all these pictures:

[image]

Thank you & greetings,

Malte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your ....\your AndroidSDK\platforms\android-11\data\res\drawable-mdpi\btn_check_off_selected.png

you can get all images which android system used.

Thats it